# Operator norm of integration operator to the power n

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

I'm working on an assignment in 'Functional Analysis' by Haase. It is as follows:

We define the integration operator $J: \mathrm{L}^2(a,b) \to \mathrm{C}[a, b]$ as
$$
(Jf)(t) := \int_a^t f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \langle f, \mathrm{1}_{(a, t)}\rangle_{\mathrm{L}^2} \quad \quad (t\in[a,b],\,f\in\mathrm{L}^2(a,b))
$$

Determine the operator norm $\left\lVert J^n \right\rVert$ of $J^n$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ acting on $\mathrm{C}[a,b]$ with the supremum norm.

**My attempted solution**

In the book it is already stated that the operator norm is equal to $\frac{1}{n!}$.

The definition of the operator norm is
$$
     \left\lVert J^n\right\rVert:= \sup_{\substack{f\in\mathrm{L}^2(a,b) \\ \left\lVert f\right\rVert\leq 1}} \left\lVert J^nf\right\rVert_\infty = \sup_{t\in[a,b]} \left| \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_a^t (t - s)^{n-1}f(s)\mathrm{d} s  \right|
     \leq \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \sup_{t\in[a,b]} \int_a^t (t - s)^{n-1}|f(s)| \mathrm{d} s.
$$

**Lower bound**

Assuming that $b - a > 1$, then certainly $f(s) = \frac{1}{(b - a)^n}$ has norm less than or equal to one. Then we can get $\left\lVert J^n\right\rVert \geq \frac{1}{n!}$. But what about the case $b - a < 1$?

**Upper bound**

I can pull the absolute values inside the integral, but then I do not see how to proceed. I can use Cauchy-Schwarz, but then I get the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of this (integration) operator. This norm is too big I believe (and cannot involve a 'simple' $n!$, as we square the kernel function)

Any help/tips are appreciated!

**EDIT**

The book stated that the solution is $\frac{1}{n!}$ while it should have been $\frac{(b-a)^n}{n!}$. Thanks to @geetha290krm for pointing this out!

The big mistake is that I did not realize that the domain and the target of $J$, is $\mathrm{C}[a,b]$. This makes things a lot easier. If someone has a solution if we consider $J: \mathrm{L}^2(a,b) \to \mathrm{C}[a,b]$ feel free to post it!

Comment: Define your operator $J$.

Comment: Your choice of $f$ does not have norm $1$, so the lower bound is wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm, thanks! I edited my question. The norm of f can also be less than 1 right? I thought this is an equivalent formulation of the operator norm (norm equal to one or less than one).

Comment: You have to divide by the norm of the input if the norm is not equal to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|J^{n}\|\leq \frac 1 {(n-1)!}\int_a^{t}(t-s)^{n-1}ds\leq \frac {(b-a)^{n}} {n!}$ when $\|f\| \leq 1$

and the choice $f=1$ gives $\|J^{n}\|\geq \frac {(b-a)^{n}} {n!}$. Hence, $\|J^{n}\|= \frac {(b-a)^{n}} {n!}$.